# Painting kitchen cabinets

Tags: kitchens, paint, cabinets

I am getting ready to paint my kitchen cabinets and need some advice on best way to go about it.  what is the best way to prep kitchen cabinets for painting and what is the best way to paint them, brush, roller, spray painter?

Also any special type of paint I should use?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This can be complicated. It depends on what finish is on there now. Paint; latex or oil. Clear, varnish or lacquer. Not all paint will stick to all of these. I would recommend that the end result will be dependent on how much work you put into it. So this is what I would do if I was looking for a quality job. # and remove doors & drawers. Patch any dings with wood putty, sand imperfections smooth, wipe down with tsp for better paint adhesion, wipe down with clean damp rag, let dry, use shellac based primer. (only finish that will stick to all other finishes) use a sanding sponge to make smooth. Brush on new paint, oil or latex.

Answer (score 2):

You first want to make sure any oils are cleaned off. Then give it a light to medium sanding. You make the call of what it needs. If any chips, fill in with wood putty/filler. Prime it for painting. In regards to best way... you need to know your abilities. In the field we spray cabinets. But if I had a choice between brush or roller, most certainly a brush is better and paint with the grains and looks out for drips, especially if painting on a flat surface. You can always use a roller for fast coverage but have a brush nearby. To me brush looks the best and I like the slight paint lines it leaves as if it is grain strokes. Either way take your time and expect 2 or more coats.

Comment: I would add that an alkyd (oil based) paint would end up giving you a harder, more durable surface but it's a pain to use. Either way you need to use the best brushes you can afford to get the best finish. And no primer is necessary unless the cabinets are raw unfinished wood.

Answer (score -1):

When I stared painting I was given one by a professional painting friend to wise up out of the buying cheap idea, and I have never looked back. They feature long, fine tightly packed bristle that glides , holds paint in measure and controls beautifully making it the best paint brush according to reviews. You can always use a roller for fast coverage but have a brush nearby. To me brush looks the best and I like the slight paint lines it leaves as if it is grain strokes.